# How to return value from a file to router layer using nodejs and expressjs

Tags: node.js, express

i have above api in TestRouter.js
**TestRouter.js**

```
router.get('/all', function(req, resp) {
    var data = reportBo.getAll();
    console.log(data);
    resp.status(200);
    resp.send(data);
    return resp;
});
```

i am calling getAll() from TestRouter.js to TestDao.js.
it is working fine and can fetch the data and can print in console. but i am trying to send this result to TestRouter.js and i am trying to print it on console. but it is showing `undefined`.

**TestDao.js**

```
module.exports.getAll = function () {
    var connection = myDB.get();
    connection.collection('REPORTS').find({}).toArray(function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        } else {
            //console.log(result);
            return result;            
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: This is an asynchronous call. You'll have to handle it in async way.

Comment: can you tell me how to do that

Comment: Please check the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
module.exports.getAll = function (callback) {
    var connection = myDB.get();
    connection.collection('REPORTS').find({}).toArray(function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            callback(err);
        } else {
            //console.log(result);
            callback(null, result);            
        }
    });
};
```

And in your router:

```
router.get('/all', function(req, resp) {
    reportBo.getAll(function(err, data){
      if(err){
         resp.status(500);
      } else {  
        resp.status(200);
        resp.send(data);
      }
    });
});
```

This way of doing things with callbacks is quite common in Node JS. Also, there is a better way called Promises. You can read up on it.